# Recommended way to render a dynamic React.js page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on building a web app using React.js, which will load data from an internal API. I've never really set up React properly before, so I'm having some trouble getting the page to load in a timely manner. I think it's because I bundle all of my JSX components using babelify, which grows quickly as I require more npm modules.

Currently, I'm compiling all of my React components and their required modules using the following build command, where client/main.js is the entry point.

```
browserify -t [ babelify ] client/main.js | uglifyjs -mc warnings=false > dist/bundle.js
```

I then link to 'dist/bundle.js' in my index.html file, which is rendered. It was working well until I required the 'request' module in one of my components, which I'm assuming greatly increased the size of bundle.js. Now, whenever I try to load the page, it takes AGES (about a minute or two). I know there's many different ways to set up a React page, so I was just wondering if I could get any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong, or what I should be doing to avoid this latency.

Comment: Requiring npm modules is completely fine. I also doubt request is big enough to cause you minute long wait times. You should do some more research. Inspect the output file sizes, figure out what's causing the file size. Maybe the files download quickly, but you have some buggy code which delays execution.

Comment: I really think it's the request module, because even if I require the module without using it, my page loading time spikes dramatically.